# Console application becomes ghost and does not show on task manager processes tab

Tags: c#

My program uses MSSQL database and has been working fine. However, after making some changes including converting from VS2008 to VS2010, generating 32bit application. It starts having the following strange problem:
When I try to shutdown the console by clicking the system menu(X button), it does not shutdown, you can move the console around, you can also click on the left hand system menu such as properties, etc, but the program does not show up on the taskmanger's processes tab, therefore, there is no way to shut it down, but to restart box.

Also, while the program is in this ghost mode, I can actually start another instance. That means the ghost application already release most of the resources such as file handle, db etc.

The problem seems to occur after we have some issues with ms-sql server, such as time out exception.  I simulate the situation by throwing an exception in the same db function call, but that does create the ghost situation. box is Windows Server Standard without Hyper-V, SP2, 32bit.

Comment: To clarify, you have a console application running in a command prompt window on a server?

Comment: If throwing an exception from a block making a DB call reproduces the problem then you should be looking at what does not occur (i.e., what code does not run as it would normally) after the exception is thrown.

Comment: This is probably a silly question but does it show up in taskmanager before you try and close it? Are you checking prcesses from all users. Does it happen in debug, is it only on the machine you deployed to? If I was stumped I'd be adding a logfile (given I didn't have one already, which I would for this sort of thing), and start writing to it, garner some clues.

Comment: This is environmental.  Hard to guess what might be wrong until you attach a debugger to the conhost.exe process and get a good stack trace.

Comment: It is console app, release build, no form, no windows. It shows on Task Manager or App and processes tab initially. When user clicks on the cmd prompt console's X-system-menu, the program shutdown straightway. The program will usually be restarted during weekend, that's when it may run into the issue it was closed and logs show that it exists Main() and therefore leave nothing in task manager, but a ghost console prompt that shows stale messages. The problem will not occur on my other OS such as Win7, XP. Since there is no process shown, how am I going to attach a debugger remotely.

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you reboot your computer after 'ghost application' appears?
If not, check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982551/en-us